# How do I disable the default handler HttpForbiddenHandler for viewing .cs files?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5, httphandler, httpforbiddenhandler

I want to be able to view the code behind files from the browser while in the development stage. To do this, I would disable the default handler of `.cs` files, `HttpForbiddenHandler` in the web.config.

Since I am using IIS 7, I first placed the `<remove>` element in `<system.webServer>` section like this:

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        <remove path="*.cs" verb="*"/>
        <add verb="*" path="*.cspx" type="HandlersAndModules.CspxHandler, HandlersAndModules" name="CspxHandler"/>
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

and I got the error when I run the application:

```
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.
```

This is because the  element in  in `<system.webServer>` section does not recognize attributes `verb` and `path`.

Then I tried moving  `<remove>` element to `<system.web>` section like this:

```
<system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
        <remove path="*.cs" verb="*"/>
    </httpHandlers>
</system.web>
```

and I got the error when I run the application:

```
HTTP Error 500.23 - Internal Server Error
An ASP.NET setting has been detected that does not apply in Integrated managed pipeline mode.
```

How do I disable the default handler `HttpForbiddenHandler` that prevents `.cs` files from being viewed from the browser?

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 things:

First, to get `.cs` files served as content, you need to add this:

```
<system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
        <remove path="*.cs" verb="*"/>
        <add verb="GET" path="*.cs" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
    </httpHandlers>
</system.web>
```

Second, to avoid `HTTP Error 500.23`, add this as a workaround:

```
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
</system.webServer>
```

`500.23` error indicates that not all your handlers and modules are specified in `system.webServer` section. If you're in position to specify them there, then do that instead of the workaround. The workaround just buys you time till you're able to migrate your settings.